# subprocceses are still alive after parent process was stopped

Tags: python

I wrote a python daemon. After I stop it I see in the memory that its sub processes are still alive and have parent with pid=1. what should I do to kill these child processes while stopping the daemon?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the multiprocessing library, you should set the [daemon](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) flag to True before starting a subprocess. This will make it exit when the parent exits.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the equivalent python call, but in C the accepted policy is to do a waitpid/wait(3) with WNOHANG option on the child pid.

the parent id is set to 1 => the init process as the parent has died and made the child process an orphan.

the c code for this is as follows

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
/*
pid_t wait(int *stat_loc);
*/

void makeOrphanPidExit(pid_t pid)
{
   int stat_loc = 0;
   waitpid(pid, &stat_loc, WNOHANG);
}
```

Calling `makeOrphanPidExit(orphanPid)` will make the child process come out of its orphanly funk! :)

Documentation on wait(3) - http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait

UPDATE:

The equivalent python call is `os.waitpid(pid, os.WNOHANG) as per http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/os.html#os.waitpid

Comment: ps -ef | grep "process cmd line" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' will give you the pid of any process which was started with "process cmd line"

Comment: usually, we dump each process's pid to a pidfile and write a thin wrapper to get the pid of the spawned processes. master.pid child_func1.pid child_func2.pid etc.